# Mean of a discrete function

Tags: functions, average, means

I have a set of finite variables (~20) which when plotted are forming a decaying exponential function. I want to know is there a better way to calculate the average of this function than by just averaging its value at these 20 points.

I know mean is { f(x1)+f(x2)+ ............... +f(x20)}/20

But I would like to know if there is a better way.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mean of a continuous function with a discrete set of values is usually approximated with rectangle method, midpoint method or trapezoid method.

The best way is usually trapezoid, which is calculated as :
$$\frac{1}{x_n-x_0}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{x_{k+1}-x_k}{2}(f(x_k)+f(x_{k+1}))$$

Comment: Can you tell me why this rule is used? Or could you point me to an article that explains the same

Comment: Sure, [Trapezoid method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) is a method to approximate integral with a finite set of point, and the average value of $f$ on $[a,b]$ is defined as $\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(t)dt$

Comment: How to look at it from a perspective which does not involve thinking about the integral or approximating the integral

Comment: There are several type of means, I'm using here continuous mean, while you are using arithmetic mean. For a continous function, continous mean is more relevant. Why do integral bother you ?

Comment: Because this is a discrete function and I don't know the probable accuracy of equating it to an integral

Comment: Oh ok, I actually understood this was a continuous function estimated with a finite set of points. Then what are you expecting to be the average value ? How is the arithmetic mean you are using irrelevant to you ?

Comment: It is not irrelevant. I am trying to find if there is a better method

Comment: Well there are several ways to look at a mean, arithmetic mean is just one of them (maybe take a look to geometric, harmonic, quadratic..), or maybe could you also try with median (well I'm not saying its a mean, but it could be relevant is some cases).